# Killing abandoned console on Heroku

Tags: console, heroku

I have accidentally closed a Heroku console in a not-so-graceful manner. And now when I run

```
heroku ps --app myapp
```

it shows

```
run.8         up for 5h           bundle exec rails console
run.9         complete for 15m    bundle exec rails console
web.1         up for 4h           bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./..
web.2         up for 4h           bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./..
worker.1      up for 4h           bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

Any way I could close the *run.8* process and stop having to pay for that one-off dyno?

Comment: it's `heroku ps --app myapp`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try

```
heroku ps:stop run.8
```

Got this from another SO answer.

Comment: This does work on Cedar for me. `heroku restart` did not kill the process. Just run `heroku ps`, grab the process name, and then run `heroku ps:stop yourprocessname` to kill it.

Answer (score 6):

On Cedar you run

heroku ps

and get

`Process   State       Command`
--------  ----------  ------------------------------------
`run.1     up for 16h  bundle exec rails console`

then run

`heroku stop run.1`

to kill it

Replace run.1 with the process name from the output above e.g. it might be `run.12` or `web.10` for a web dyno or `worker.16` for a worker.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried just restarting the app - is that possible to do?

```
heroku restart
```

Comment: Just to follow up on this - I've recently experienced this and found that restarting the app didn't actually clear them. I logged it with support and got told there wasn't actually a way to kill these processes and that all processes are restarted every 24hrs.